# Why Totem doesn't automatically load subtitles with .txt extension?

Tags: totem, subtitle

In Ubuntu 20.04, Totem doesn't automatically load subtitles when subtitle file has .txt extension. If I load the subtitle file manually the subtitles work. But they aren't loaded automatically with the video.
The option "Automatically load subtitle files" in preferences is checked, and if the subtitle file has the extension .srt, it is loaded automatically. But for .txt it isn't.
I have a bunch of old subtitle files with .txt extensions moved from old Ubuntu 10.04 machine (where Totem did load .txt files automatically) and I'd like to be able to watch them without the need to manually load subtitles each time.

Comment: Could you simply rename all ? `shopt -s globstar; rename 's/\.txt$/.srt/'  Movies/**/*.txt`

Comment: They aren't in SRT format, so that extension would be misguding.

Comment: I found out that the file responsible for loading subtitles is /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/totem/plugins/autoload-subtitles/libautoload-subtitles.so . Inside that file, I can see the extension list: sub,srt,smi,ssa,ass,asc. So it looks like the extension txt is simply not included in the code, but I can't understand why, since it's one of the most popular for subtitles and all hardware players recognize this extension.
I decided to hex-edit the file and replace "asc" with "txt". That worked for me, however if the file gets updated, the procedure will have to be repeated.